# Is there a way to use GWT static string i18n with server-provided properties?

Tags: gwt

I am searching a solution for a tricky question.
I would like to use GWT static string internationalization, thus using Constants, ConstantsWithLookup and Messages, but the strings must come from the server at runtime, instead that compile time.

Is there already a project that does such a thing, or should I write my own GWT generators?

Thanks to everyone that will help me.

**UPDATE**: The Dictionary is not an option, because the application is almost complete and I cannot change all the application for this.

**UPDATE 2**: In fact Dictionary is an option if it is wrapped by a Costants-like or Messages-like interface.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is not static i18n at all.  Some of the reasons why GWT's i18n is virtually all static:

- It is a synchronous API.  Fetching resources from the server will either require an async API to spread throughout the entire application (ie, passing a Future to a widget telling it where to get its inner text once that string has been fetched from the server) or you will have to basically block execution of the app until the i18n resources have been downloaded at the beginning (which will give poor experience for users).
- We can optimize the generated code to only include those formatters and associated data that are actually needed by the messages in the app.  If you don't include any plural messages, we don't have to include that code, etc.  Expressions can be inlined, dead code removed, and class references removed entirely in most cases.
- We can make use of things at compile time that would be hard or expensive to do at runtime.  For example, simply parsing the message format strings takes a fair amount of code, and none of that needs to be included in the compiled output.  Let's say you fetch strings for your app from the server, and you find that one of them has {0,localtime,YMd} in it -- now you need ICU4J in order to localize that -- oops!  Even if it could all be compiled to JS, it would be huge.  Perhaps you can support a subset of GWT's i18n in this way, but you will have to include every formatter that might possibly be referenced from a message, even though most of them never would be.

If you really want dynamic i18n, then do as the other answers suggest and use Dictionary (note however that you won't be able to properly localize your app if it has any complexity to its messages).  If you need more than can be provided by that, then bite the bullet and use static i18n.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I already know about Dictionary and this is not an option, simply because the application is complete (or almost complete) and now I would like to add a (almost) seamless integration.

Comment: Great advice from @jat, a man who's been inside the GWT compiler more than most. Couldn't say it better.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options: Good and Less Good.

**Good:**
The standard way, [static string i18n](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n?hl=fr#DevGuideStaticStringInternationalization) were all language permutations are optimized and inlined where they are used (i.e. put the Japanese company name into the HTML template for a button/column/header).

Because the full suite of i18n can be elaborate with support for pluralization and message builders, @nnoations, and automatic i18n, it is preferable. It is also the *fastest* option for performance.

**Less Good:**
Often because you need to work with a legacy system, so Good is not good enough. Here rather than all the rocket widgets, you just need to get text in boxes. Then use the [dynamic string i18n](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n?hl=fr#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization) and drop the strings into your page with something like an old school Dictionary object.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, however what they want is, in fact, avoid rebuilding the application.

Comment: As an addition, my idea is to use a modified version of the I18N generators that would create classes that use an internal map. This map will be loaded by a request factory call (or GWT-RPC) once.

Comment: Again however, i18n is inlined at compile time. You'd need to use something separate from the i18n/permutations at compile time as you want this to be runtime.